# Boolean intersect with all shape keys of target object

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys

I have two objects, one lying inside the other, such that the outer object is like some kind of shell surrounding the inner one. I have a boolean difference modifier set to the outer object, its target being the inner one, so that the resulting mesh is just the area between the inner and outer objects. Think of it at a watermelon, the inner object being the red core, and the outer object being the green rind encasing it.

The inner object has shape keys, which are to later serve for animation.

What I want to do now is apply the boolean modifier permanently to the outer object, but I want the resultant mesh to retain the animation resulting from movement of the inner object.

In essence I have 4 shape keys in my inner object, and I want to apply the boolean difference operation to the outer object 4 times, one for each shape key in the inner object, and have the resulting meshes stored in corresponding shape keys created in the outer object.

I hope I've been able to accurately convey what I'm trying to do.